# Switching between two DIVs by clicking on them (with no button)

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I'm working with Bootstrap collapsing options and currently I have this:

```
<div class="card">
    <a data-target="#collapse1" data-toggle="collapse">
        <div class="cardbody">
        <div class="collapse show" id="collapse1">
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut sed ligula sollicitudin, facilisis lacus sit amet, ullamcorper metus. Aliquam finibus aliquet sem, maximus tincidunt erat. Etiam sollicitudin dui pharetra, ultrices felis vitae, tincidunt odio. Nullam fringilla porttitor purus in vulputate. Maecenas quam tortor, auctor nec bibendum at, ornare condimentum arcu. Duis a diam scelerisque, dignissim mi a, ultricies lacus. 
        </div>
     </div>
      </a>
    </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cwh0xo2e/1/

As you can see, it is possible to click anywhere on the card and it will toggle collapse function back and forth.

But is there a noble solution to switch between two different divs in a similar fashion?

Comment: You want 2 divs, and to hide any of the divs when it is clicked?

Comment: Yes, Justinas option works great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, hide one and show another div:

```js
function toggleDivs() {
  $('.content').toggleClass('active')
}
```

```css
.content {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 30px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: none;
}

.active {
  display: block;
}

.c1 {
  background-color: red;
}

.c2 {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="wrapper" onClick="toggleDivs()">
  <div class="active content c1"> CONTENT 1</div>
  <div class="content c2"> CONTENT 2 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh, this is perfect! I was trying to use`accordion` in bootstrap but it was such a pain. Thanks!